# WSS over Secure SSL connection fails only on FireFox with error 1006

Tags: node.js, ssl, firefox, websocket

My website runs on https/ssl (valid CA certificate) on IIS 10.0 (iisnode 0.2.21) / node/express. I am using a websocket server on top of https server (same port)

However the websocket connection works very well for CHrome and IE11. It fails only for Firefox (version 80) with error code 1006 [(error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpOGy.png))

in Inspector / Network console, it gives the following error[error as shown in network under inspector console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtWn0.png)

In the web.config file, I have added the following line
`<webSocket enabled="false"/>`

app.js code is as below:

```
var cors = require('cors');
var createError = require('http-errors');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const https = require("https");
// var app = express();
var app = require('express-ws-routes')();

.....

var wsRouter = require("./routes/wsRoute"); // route for Websocket

....
app.use('/ws', wsRouter);

....
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 443);
```

In my Websocket route, I use the following code

```
router.websocket('/', function(info, cb,  next) {
    
    var connid = info.req.query.connid;
    var pgid = info.req.query.pageid;

    cb(function(socket) {   
        // socket is connected   
        socket.send(JSON.stringify({'response_type':'WSConnActive',
                            'response':{"status":"success","details":"Welcome Message","reqOrigin":"Home","welcomeMsg":'Hello '+usr+', Welcome! you are now connected!'}}));

....
 socket.on('message', function incoming(message) {  // handle message }

socket.on("close", function socketClose(ws){
            console.log(info.req.query.usr+" closed session at "+moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
            var usrClose = info.req.query.usr;
...}
});  });
```

At the client end I connect
`var socket = new WebSocket('wss://<host>:443/ws?request_type=init&usr='+UserID+'&connid='+connectTime+'&pageid='+page_ID);`

All this works as expected for Chrome and IE11 except firefox

I am not sure where the issue is.. any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the WSS working on Firefox with help of the note found in iisnode githun ([https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/497][1]) !. Issue seemed to be with iisnode configuration, In addition t , i had create a HTTP_CONNECTION server variable and add rewrite rules as below,

````
                  <match url="ws/*" />      
                  <serverVariables>
                      <set name="HTTP_CONNECTION" value="Upgrade" />
                  </serverVariables>                    
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="websocket-server.js" />
            </rule> ```




  [1]: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/issues/497
````